# Generic Matrix Class with Underlying template based memory management in C++

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I'm in the process of writing a cuda based image processing library mostly for fun and learning purposes seeing as though opencv already has plenty of algorithms and operations in their cuda source.

What I would like to do is generify the inputs to my functions so that I can apply my cuda kernels to different data types (i.e. an 8 bit image as well as a 16 bit grayscale image) but I'm struggling to get a good working example with templates and inheritance. What I've tried is multiple inheritance, with no luck.

For example I have the following function in gimage.h

```
void GIMAGE_EXPORT test(Matrix a, Matrix b, Matrix out, int size);
```

The class Matrix looks like this (it is just an abstract class).

```
class GIMAGE_EXPORT Matrix {
    public:
        Matrix(Type type, size_t size);
        Type type();
        size_t size();
        template<typename T>
        T* data() {
            return nullptr;
        }

    private:
        size_t _size;
        Type _type;
    };
```

Then this is where it get's interesting. I have a template class called InputArray that takes care of the actual memory management.

```
template<typename T>
    class GIMAGE_EXPORT InputArray {
    public:
        InputArray() {
            _size = 0;
        }

        InputArray(size_t size) {
            _size = size;
            allocate(size);
        }

        ~InputArray() {
            delete[] data;
        }

        T* getData() {
            return data;
        }

        T get(int index) {
            return data[index];
        }

        void setData(T elem, int index) {
            data[index] = elem;
        }

        size_t totalSize() {
            return sizeof(T)*_size;
        }

        size_t size() {
            return _size;
        }
    private:
        void allocate(size_t size) {
            data = new T[size];
        }
        size_t _size;
        T* data;
    };
```

Then I make specific versions of the Matrix, namely MatrixUint16 and MatrixUint8. These both inherit from Matrix, but also inherit from specializations from InputArray and InputArray respectively.

These classes look like this (array.h)

```
class GIMAGE_EXPORT MatrixUint16 : public Matrix, public InputArray < uint16_t > {
public:
    MatrixUint16(size_t size);
    uint16_t* data();
};

class GIMAGE_EXPORT MatrixUint8 : public Matrix, public InputArray < uint8_t  {
public:
    MatrixUint8(size_t size);
    uint8_t* data();
};
```

And the definitiions: (array.cpp)

```
Matrix::Matrix(Type type, size_t size) {
    _size = size;
    _type = type;
}

Type Matrix::type() {
    return _type;
}

size_t Matrix::size() {
    return _size;
}

MatrixUint16::MatrixUint16(size_t size) : Matrix(TYPE_UINT16, size) , InputArray<uint16_t>(size){
}

uint16_t* MatrixUint16::data() {
    return getData();
}

MatrixUint8::MatrixUint8(size_t size) : Matrix(TYPE_UCHAR, size), InputArray<uint8_t>(size) {

}

uint8_t* MatrixUint8::data() {
    return getData();
}
```

Now when I test the arrays like this (using GTEST)

```
gimage::MatrixUint16 a(3);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    a.setData((uint16_t)i, i);
}
EXPECT_EQ(a.get(0), 0);
EXPECT_EQ(a.get(1), 1);
EXPECT_EQ(a.get(2), 2);
```

All is well and the tests pass.

Now in my function (void test(blah...)) I try to get the raw data pointer by doing the following:

```
uint16_t* data = a.data<uint16_t>();
```

But if I try to read anything from the array (i.e. data[0]) I get a SEH Exception.

Is there any way to keep the inputs to my function generic and then figure out at runtime what data type is in there? I need to know this because I have to allocate memory to the GPU before calling my kernel so I need the size of the explicit type (i.e. sizeof(uint16_t)*numelements).

I'm basically looking for the same (ish) functionality as opencv::Mat but without a lot of the complexity that comes with it (I don't need to support every possible image type).

I should note that I can't make the function a template because then it would have to be defined in the header and the library could only be used in .cu files. I want to generate a .dll that can be linked to and used from C++ code so that all the GPU code is hidden from the user in the dll.

If anyone could provide any other alternatives to what I want to do that would be great.

For completeness the library can be seen here: https://github.com/DeveloperPaul123/gimage

Comment: The CUDA tag should be removed, since your question is related to pure C++ templates and polymorphism, with no code related to the CUDA API at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix is not abstract.  When you ask for `.data<Foo>()` this implementation is called:

```
    template<typename T>
    T* data() {
        return nullptr;
    }
```

You cannot have a virtual template method: there is no way to have a template abstract method.

Your design is impractical.

A pure virtual `get_data_internal` that returns a `void*`, and make your 1get_data`do a`static_cast(get_data_internal())`might solve your problem, but I do not see the utility of a common`Matrix` class with polymorphic storage so I do not know if it is a good idea.

I would implement some concrete matrix types and use a traits class to map to them, or manually export a set of templates from the library, maybe wrapping particular memory types by size in an exposed template shim, or whatever.

Comment: Yes I knew that was happening with the null pointer. I tried what you mentioned with a virtual method, but this still did not work. Could you provide more info on what you would implement either with a traits class or a template shim? I'm not convinced that this would solve the issue of having a generic class to input into the kernel function.

Comment: @DeveloperPaul I assume you cannot, or at least should not, use a virtual method in a kernal function.

Comment: Actually I just revisited this idea and it seems to work. I have now a pure abstract class as the base class. The template InputArray class inherits from this class and is forced to override the getData function to get a pointer to the underlying function. By keeping track of what data type InputArray is I can use the abstract class as an input to my function by passing it in by reference. Just tested it and this works and for my purposes should be good enough.

Comment: The virtual function is being passed to my cpp function, the kernel itself is a template kernel.